# How do I sustain JavaScript execution with custom error handling in IE6?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am writing an application that will have some users on Internet Explorer 6. These users on IE6 have their browsers set to debug JavaScript errors. If a JS error occurs on the page, a window will pop-up and the user is asked if they would like to 'continue running scripts on this page'.

However, my application has its own internal try/catch system for handling/logging errors and prompting the user what to do. In my error handling system, I distinguish between fatal errors and non-fatal errors. With non-fatal errors, the user is prompted to re-try after a moment and we allow JavaScript to continue executing. With fatal errors (e.g., data needed for rendering the initial page load is missing), JavaScript execution is halted to prevent further error and the user is prompted to reload the page.

The problem with IE6 is that when script debugging is turned on, JavaScript execution is halted no matter what--there's no opportunity for the user to press the 'Yes, continue running scripts on this page'. So even if the error was non-fatal, it's game over, user has to reload the page.

Does anyone know a way to get around this and prevent IE6 from halting JavaScript execution? Unfortunately, asking my users to change their IE settings is not an option.

Comment: I don't know the background of your situation, but IE6 was proclaimed officially dead a few months ago now, so it's not necessarily up to you to support it any more. Of course if you've still got users on IE6 then you've got no choice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, certain errors will always halt JavaScript execution in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

I felt we got off on the wrong foot and I think this is a valid question that deserves an answer. Digging into this issue for you - what you are trying to accomplish is to essentially give an IE6 specific directive to the client to cease exception bubbling

There is a useful (perhaps) article about the IE6 debugger and it's related scriptable bits :

overview : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx

debugger directive MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bwt76sk(vs.71).aspx

Therein you can find references to both Debugger and Stop directives. This is an old article (04) and it was the most relevant to your issue I could find. Good luck.

Comment: I see what you are saying now - so is this being generated from an async request/response ? if so you are NOT using the `XMLHttpRequest` for IE6 clients, right? if you are - **thats your problem right there**

for IE 6 you need to use the activeX object for asnyc bits n pieces

Comment: Oh I really did misinterpret what you were trying to accomplish!  I would suggest adding a "coding-practice" tag to the question.

One thought though : The purpose of debug mode IS TO CEASE page processing so you can examine the issue @ hand. This is a "feature" rather than a "bug" - you may find yourself trying to proverbially "out fox a fox". Good luck!

Comment: I think you're reading too fast. you stated : " **The problem with IE6 is that when script debugging is turned on ** "  --- modifying that behavior is likely beyond the security model. "Debugging" I referred to is the IE6 native mode you mentioned. This is an application "feature"

Answer (score -1):

Perform more thorough checking of any input data. Errors just should not appear at all.

BTW, consider using JSONP instead of XHR -- failing to load a file (JSONP) should not trigger JS exception.